# How do I use multiple Slick Syncing Sliders with Angular To Avoid Images from not appearing when switching between syncing sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, carousel, slick.js

I'm currently working on an **Angular**, **jQuery** website that uses Carousels on most pages,  I have a gallery page that currently let's the user select which gallery they want to view. I'm using the Slick syncing slider on this page, and am currently doing an  `ng-show/hide` to show the proper gallery that has been selected by the user.

the html and js is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
  });


  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true
  });

});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="gallery in galleries">
  <div ng-show="gallery.showGallery">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="slider-for">
        <div ng-repeat="path in gallery.galleryImages">
          <img src="images/{{path}}" style="width:200px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="slider-nav">
      <div ng-repeat="path in gallery.galleryImages">
        <img src="images/{{path}}" style="width:200px;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the button it changes the show Gallery property of the object to be true and all others false, all are initially set to true but on page load all but one gallery's `showGallery` property is set to false.

Currently the show and hide works, but if you use the navigation portion of the carousel and then select a different gallery the main section does not show a picture until you start using the navigation again. I have come to find out that due to the **jQuery** portion that is run on the ready to initialize the carousel all the galleries are sharing the same listener so when you are using the navigation of one it cycles through the other galleries images in the background as well.

I need to know if anyone has worked with multiple syncing sliders on one page and found a fix or had similar issues to this. Ideally I'd like to avoid having to forget using angular destroy the `DOM` element and then rebuild it and run the slick function, would also like to avoid using a cookie or session object to just reload the page with the users new selection as the main choice.